# C Using Libraries Without IDE

Tags: libraries, c

This may be a stupid question. How do you use C libraries without an IDE? I want to only use a text editor.

Comment: Write your code with any plain text editor and save as *.c file. Then run your compiler and linker with the necessary parameters and you will get the executable. That is exactly the same the IDE does, you just leave out the UI and type manually. I would recommend you writing a script for that then.

Comment: Without saying which library, the best I can say is use the `-l` flag for `gcc`/`g++`/`ld` appropriately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(does this really belong here)?

Example: using the math library. Create this file with your preferred editor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>  //this declare the math library 

int main() {
        printf("%f\n", sin(1.0)); // using math and stdio library 
        return 0;
}
```

Then you compile:

```
gcc -o test test.c -lm -lc
```

Read: compile `test.c` to an executable called `test` using the libraries `libc` and `libm` (Notice: you do not need to use explicitly `-lc -lm` because they are linked in by default when needed; this is just an example --- other libraries you *have* to explicitly tell).

Run it:

```
[romano:~/tmp] % ./test                    
0.841471
```

Voilá.

You can get information for the library using section 3 of the man pages; for example 
[`man 3 sin`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sin.3):

> ```
> SIN(3)                     Linux Programmer's Manual                  SIN(3)
>
> NAME
>        sin, sinf, sinl - sine function
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        #include <math.h>
>
>        double sin(double x);
> ```
>
> [...]

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the simple steps:

1. Open up any text-editor you want to write your program in.
2. Write a simple program, or any program in C, you want.
3. - Now if you want to add any library in you program, it has the same procedure as it is in an IDE. For example I want to add a library in program named as system library, then I would write:

     ```
     #include<sys/types.h>
     ```

     and then write my rest of the program.
   - now save the file anywhere you want, with an extension of `.c`. For example: I saved my first file on my desktop, name as `HelloWorld.c`.
4. In terminal, go to the directory where you have saved your file.
5. Type the following command to create an executable file in the same directory:

   ```
   gcc –o executable HelloWorld.c
   ```
6. This creates a file named as `executable` in the same directory where the .c file is present.
7. To run the executable file, type the following command:

   ```
   ./executable
   ```

   and this prints or performs the tasks of your program.

In a nutshell, whatever you use to write the C program, whether its a text editor or an IDE like dev c++, it will work same. IDEs just save your time in writing those commands every time to compile the program.

Happy Coding :)